# Eigenvalues of Angular momentum $L^2$ and $L_z$ for a complex function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, eigenvalue

I was given the following function:
$$\Psi(t=0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[(Y_{1,1})+i(Y_{1,-1})\right],$$
where $Y_{lm}$ refers to the standard spherical harmonic function. I am trying to come up with the expectation values for $L^2$, $L_z$ and $L_x$, but I am running into trouble.

$$\langle L^2\rangle=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\hbar l(l+1)+\left(i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\hbar l(l+1)=0$$

$$\langle L_z\rangle=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\hbar m+\left(i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\hbar (-m)=\hbar m$$

I am not sure how to compute $L_x$, but the above result already looks impossible, in light of:
$$L^2=L_x^2+L_y^2+L_z^2.$$

I would like to know where the mistake in my reasoning is. Thank you!

Comment: Haven't you come across the operators $L_+$ and $L_-$ in your studies? You should be able to use that information to find $L_x$ so you can then compute it's expectation value.

Comment: I hadn't yet: we just started, and it's my first Quantum course. I am reading up on it now; but either way it is not inside (this chapter) of the course material. Thanks for the help!

Comment: note that when taking the exepectation value, you have to **conjugate** the bra-vector. As a general rule-of-thumb, the **expectation value** of a Hermitian operator is always real (though it might have matrix elements that are complex)

Comment: Thank you, yyy! So what you are you saying - in practice in this case - is that I should replace i with 1 in the above calculations? If so, that is really helpful!

Comment: yes. In the above calculations the $i^2=-1$ should be $i\times (-i)=1$

Comment: That's really strange that this isn't addressed here. What book are you using?

Comment: replacing $i$ by $1$ will get you in trouble.  what you want is not $(1/\sqrt{2})^2$ or $(i/\sqrt{2})^2)$ but $\vert i/\sqrt{2}\vert^2$ etc.

Answer (score 3):

Representing the states  as $|l,m\rangle $, We know that
$$L^2|l,m\rangle =l(l+1)\hbar^2|l,m\rangle $$
$$L_z|l,m\rangle=m\hbar |l,m\rangle $$
The state given by
$$|\psi\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1,1\rangle +i|1,-1\rangle) $$
Now, it's easy to find
$$\langle L^2\rangle =\langle \psi|L^2|\psi\rangle, \ \ \ \ \ \langle L_z\rangle =\langle \psi|L_z|\psi\rangle  $$
For $L_x$, We can use
$$L_\pm =L_x\pm iL_y\rightarrow L_x=\frac{L_++L_-}{2}$$
Further, We know
$$L_\pm |l,m\rangle =\hbar\sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m\pm 1)}|l,m\pm 1\rangle $$
Further, Note the orthonormality relation:-
$$\langle l',m'|l,m\rangle =\delta_{l,l'}\delta_{m,m'}$$
This should suffice!!

Answer (score 2):

When calculating expectation values of diagonal operators
(like $L^2$ and $L_z$), you need to
take the absolute square $|c|^2$ or $(c^*c)$ of the coefficients
of $|\Psi\rangle$, not their square $(c)^2$.
Then you get the correct values
$$\begin{align}
\langle L^2\rangle
 &=\langle\Psi|L^2|\Psi\rangle \\
 &=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right|^2\hbar^2 l(l+1)+\left|i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right|^2\hbar^2 l(l+1) \\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\hbar^2 l(l+1) + \frac{1}{2}\hbar^2 l(l+1) \\
 &=\hbar^2 l(l+1)
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\langle L_z\rangle
 &=\langle\Psi|L_z|\Psi\rangle \\
 &=\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right|^2\hbar m+\left|i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right|^2\hbar (-m) \\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\hbar m - \frac{1}{2}\hbar m \\
 &= 0
\end{align}$$

And likewise for calculating $\langle L_x\rangle$ and
$\langle L_y\rangle$ be aware, that $\langle\Psi|$ will involve
the complex conjugates.